# Autorun Application on startup 

Tags: windows-7, boot, macros

i am using Windows 7 with SP1. i want to execute one Application on startup.

1. I can add this program to "Startup" folder, where it will get started on system boot.
2. or Any Startup Managing tools, which can add the application to Startup folder.

but what i really want that, I have to autorun an application then, in that application one of the menu should be clicked automatically. is it possible to do ? any macro or kind of tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i implemented using the autohotkey software, which can recored the keystroke, even click handler. [`Auto Hot Key`](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/).